# Rotate array 180 degrees using rotate90 twice in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am fairly new to java. I just wanted to clear my doubt. Does this rotates the array by 90 degrees and then again another 90 degrees as it is in the same method or no.

This is my `rotate90` code:

```
void rotate90() {
    int temp = x;
    x = -y;
    y = temp;
}
```

And this is the calling method:

```
static void randomPattern(Screen2D window) {
    while (notFull()) {

        walk.clear();
        Point2D start = getFreePoint();
        recursiveSelfAvoidingWalk(0, start.x, start.y);

        for (Point2D pt: walk) {
            pt.rotate90();
            pt.translate(Screen2D.HEIGHT-1, 0);
        }
        Point2D [] pts = walk.toArray(new Point2D[] {});
        PolyLine myWalk = new PolyLine(pts, '#');
        myWalk.setParent(window);
        myWalk.draw();

        for (Point2D pt: walk) {
            pt.rotate90();
            pt.rotate90();
            pt.translate(Screen2D.WIDTH, Screen2D.HEIGHT);
        }
        myWalk.draw();
    }
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: Your `rotate90` method is taking the _transpose_ of the matrix (where x and y values swap).  It is _not_ doing rotation of any kind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120406/rotate-matrix-90-degrees-clockwise

Comment: Have you tested it? Also, are `x` and `y` of type `int`, `double` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are using your own Point2D class and not java.awt.geom.Point2D (because the latter does not seem to offer a rotate90 method).

As far as I see the rotation around the center at (0,0) counterclockwise is done mathematical correctly.

However rotating two times 90° is like rotating 180° or just take the inverse of the vector. So why not use

```
void rotate180() {
   x = -x;
   y = -y;
}
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : the proposed rotate90 does not  just swap x and y but also flips the sign of y. Thus it is a rotation.

Comment: My instructor asked to rotate 180° using the rotate90 method, but your response solved my question. I tried the rotate180 to test the results, and the output is identical in both cases. So, I guess this does the trick.